# unable to use source image: alpine in gitlab-ci-pipeline in AWS-fargate

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner, aws-fargate

I have a specific issue with executing jobs if a source image is using in GitLab-ci job any alpine image (test alpine/kaniko, alpine/helm ...).

Infrastructure setup: AWS-fargate-profile(containerd/1.4.1) where is running gitlab-runner,Gitlab-runner-slave are spin up on fargate's ..

Once I will try to use GitLab-runner on EKS (ec2) instances then jobs are properly executed doesn't matter of alpine/debian ..
I have tried to replace GitLab-runner-helper image for ubuntu version but still getting same error.
EKS-fargate-profile has containerd/1.4.1

I am a little bit confused about what is going wrong or differently on EC2 and fargate

**Pipeline job output:**

```
  on fargate-gitlab-runner-86c4c7c95f-swbwh XXX
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "kubernetes" executor
00:00
Using Kubernetes namespace: gitlab-runner-fg
Using Kubernetes executor with image XXX:8085/alpine/helm:3.2.1 ...
Preparing environment
01:28
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner-fg/runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j to be running, status is Pending
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
Running on runner-nkzkmtwa-project-386-concurrent-0mbm5j via fargate-gitlab-runner-86c4c7c95f-swbwh...
Getting source from Git repository
00:00
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/XXX/0/XXX/fargate-gitlab-runner/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 497e247d as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("build")
```

**config.toml**

gitlab-version 13.12

```
listen_address = ":9252"
concurrent = 50
check_interval = 3
log_level = "debug"

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "fargate-gitlab-runner-86c4c7c95f-swbwh"
  output_limit = 16384
  request_concurrency = 1
  url = "https://gitlab.example.com/"
  token = "XXX"
  executor = "kubernetes"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.kubernetes]
    host = ""
    bearer_token_overwrite_allowed = false
    image = "XX:8085/ubuntu:16.04"
    namespace = "gitlab-runner-fg"
    namespace_overwrite_allowed = ""
    privileged = false
    cpu_limit = "1500m"
    cpu_request = "1500m"
    memory_limit = "4000Mi"
    pull_policy = [""]
    image_pull_secrets = ["docker-registry-login"]
    poll_timeout = 1200
    service_account = "infra-fargate-gitlab-runner"
    service_account_overwrite_allowed = ""
    pod_annotations_overwrite_allowed = ""
    helper_image = "XX:8085/gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:ubuntu-x86_64-c97a73fa"
    [runners.kubernetes.affinity]
    [runners.kubernetes.pod_security_context]
    [runners.kubernetes.volumes]
    [runners.kubernetes.dns_config]
```